# Get related data from other tab as an array for summary in other tab

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, average, google-query-language

Imagine having the following tabs. I want to summarize (let's say avg) in a second tab per each key (room name in the example).

[image]

How can I get only values matching by key? VLOOKUP finds only a single entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({A:B}; 
 "select Col1,avg(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label avg(Col2)''")
```

---

### update:

```
=QUERY({A:B};   
 "select Col1,avg(Col2)    
  where Col1 ='"&'2nd tab'!B1&"'    
  group by Col1    
  label avg(Col2)''")
```

Comment: Almost! What I get is avg for all rooms. I want to get avg for a particular room. So the query should be like:
`select Col1,avg(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null  AND Col1 = 2nd tab!B1
  group by Col1 
  label avg(Col2)`

Comment: @DamianDrewulski then try: `=QUERY({A:B}; 
 "select Col1,avg(Col2) 
  where Col1 ='"&'2nd tab'!B1&"' 
  group by Col1 
  label avg(Col2)''")`

Comment: that's what I was looking for. Bravo!

Comment: @DamianDrewulski answer updated